# Exactly Once Two Kafka Clusters

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have 2 Kafka clusters. Cluster A and Cluster B. These clusters are completely separate.
I have a spring-boot application that listens to a topic on Cluster A transforms the event and then produces it onto Cluster B. I require exactly once as these are financial events. I have noticed that with my current application I sometimes get duplicates as well as miss some events. I have tried to implement exactly once as best I could. One of the posts said flink would be a better option over spring-boot. Should i move over to flink? Please see the Spring code below.

ConsumerConfig

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.server.consumer}")
    String server;

    @Value("${kafka.kerberos.service.name:}")
    String kerberosServiceName;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, server);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, AvroDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed");
        
        // skip kerberos if no value is provided
        if (kerberosServiceName.length() > 0) {
          config.put("security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
          config.put("sasl.kerberos.service.name", kerberosServiceName);
        }

        return config;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, AccrualSchema> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),
                new AvroDeserializer<>(AccrualSchema.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, AccrualSchema> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, AccrualSchema> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setAutoStartup(true);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.RECORD);
        
        factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaConsumerAccrual receiver() {
        return new KafkaConsumerAccrual();
    }
}
```

ProducerConfig

```
    @Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.server.producer}")
    String server;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, server);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        config.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, "prod-1");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG,"snappy");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, "10");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, Integer.toString(32*1024));
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

}
```

KafkaProducer

```
    @Service
public class KafkaTopicProducer {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;
        
    public void topicProducer(String payload, String topic) {
        kafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction(kt->kt.send(topic, payload));            
    }
}
```

KafkaConsumer

```
public class KafkaConsumerAccrual {

    @Autowired
    KafkaTopicProducer kafkaTopicProducer;

    @Autowired
    Gson gson;
 
    @KafkaListener(topics = "topicname", groupId = "groupid", id = "listenerid")
    public void consume(AccrualSchema accrual,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) Integer partition, @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) Long offset,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.CONSUMER) Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {       
        
        
        AccrualEntity accrualEntity = convertBusinessObjectToAccrual(accrual,partition,offset);

        kafkaTopicProducer.topicProducer(gson.toJson(accrualEntity, AccrualEntity.class), accrualTopic);

    }

    public AccrualEntity convertBusinessObjectToAccrual(AccrualSchema ao, Integer partition,
            Long offset) {
        //Transform code goes here
        return ae;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are they separate Kafka clusters?

Comment: Two different companies/Systems. We only require to integrate one topic of data.

Comment: This is something we cannot change unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Exactly Once semantics are not supported across clusters; the key is producing records and committing the consumed offset(s) within one atomic transaction.

That is not possible in your environment since a transaction can't span two clusters.

Comment: Is there any workaround to achieve this? 1 suggestion i got was using flink and 2 phase commit.

Comment: Is there a way to get atleast once?

Comment: I am not familiar with flink, so I can't comment on that. At least once is the default behavior with Spring for Apache Kafka.

Comment: Please can you assist and look at the code sample i sent. What would i need to change to get atleast once behaviour for this setup

Comment: One more thing gary in the event we are on the same cluster is the code above the correct implementation for exactly once?

Comment: For the multi-cluster case, you need to wait for the future returned by the `send()` to complete so that an exception is thrown if it fails and the record is redelivered. For the single cluster case, you need to wire a `KafkaTransactionManager` into the container factory and NOT use `executeInTransaction`; for EOS, the sends must be performed in the same transaction that the container starts, not a new one. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions and https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#exactly-once

Comment: Hi Gary how do i handle  public void onFailure(KafkaProducerException ex) {code here} Should i try to reproduce?

Comment: If you want to requeue the consumed record, you can't use the async failure, you need to call `get()` on the future; it will throw an exception if there is a failure.

Answer (score 0):

According to this specific Draft KIP :
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-656%3A+MirrorMaker2+Exactly-once+Semantics

The better thing that you can expect right know is an at-least-one semantic between two clusters.
It implies that you have to protect from duplication on the consumer side of the target broker.

As an example, you can identify a set a properties that must be unique for a specific windows of time. But i will really depend on your use case.